# Retrieve data from SQL to display as XML

Tags: php, sql, xml

My SQL query is this

```
  SELECT firstname AS 'User', count( * ) AS 'Number of photos uploaded'
    FROM members
    JOIN member_photo
   USING ( member_id )
GROUP BY firstname
```

Basically it is displaying data as follows:

```
User         Number of photos uploaded  
Az                   1  
Mz                   3
```

and so on..

What I want to do is transfer this data to a XML file in the form :

```
<photos>
    <user>Az</user>
    <user_photos>1</user_photos>
    <user>Mz</user>
    <user_photos>3</user_photos>
</photos>
```

or any other appropriate way.

Comment: So? What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: My knowledge of XML is really low. I didn't try anything yet. What do you suggest?

Comment: The same as Pablo Santa Cruz: do the exact same thing you would do if it were html.

Answer (score 1):

You do the exact same way you would do it if your **XML** was **HTML**.

Suppose this is your **php** script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml')'
?>
<photos>
<?php
$query = "select ... form foo...";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <user><?= $row['user'] ?></user>
    <user_photos><?= $row['photos_count'] ?></user_photos>
<?php
}
?>
</photos>
```

Comment: and how do i output it to my XML file? I have created an XML file name statistics.xml

Comment: to an xml file!? I thought you wanted to output it to your browser. if you want to output to an XML file, you will need to open the file and write to it.

Comment: yeah exactly. Do you know how to do that? Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You did not state your DBMS, but the following will work with PostgreSQL and Oracle:

```
SELECT '<photos>'||xmlforest(firstname AS "user", count( * ) AS user_photos)||'</photos>'
FROM members
  JOIN member_photo USING ( member_id )
GROUP BY firstname
```